# Google Sheets count If time within time range

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I have created a separate sheet to demonstrate what I am after I know the issue lays within the time first being greater than the second time (I.E. 7pm then 4am) but that is how it is needed,  Meaning if someone clocks on between those 3rd shift hours they will receive 3rd shift premium.  Is there a way I can make a countif for a rolling 24 hours?

This is the code I am using to check clock-in times:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(A2,">=7:00 PM",A2,"<=4:45 AM"),"TRUE","FALSE")`

My test sheet can be seen [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6HCH60drHVrjvl8xGK7Peh5IOvdGdl-_ToLliDdmNc/edit?usp=sharing), where I have made the cell that should be TRUE noticeable.

[image: My Sheet]

Comment: If too complicated I did just think after posting, I could just remove column C and if the 3 cells in that row are false do something, which would account for that time span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A3, ">=7:00 PM", A3-1, "<=4:45 AM")=1
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B3:B9, 
 {TIMEVALUE("00:00 AM"), 1; 
  TIMEVALUE("4:45:01 AM"), 2; 
  TIMEVALUE("7:00 PM"), 1}, 2, 1)=1)
```

[image: 0]